# Suburban stumbles at idle, unknown tube spewing black liquid into air intake is suspected cause. Please advise?

Tags: chevrolet, rough-idle, suburban, pcv-valve, diagnose

I have a Chevrolet Suburban 2008 1500 with the 5.3L V8 engine. A tube that I believe to be the PCV hose is spewing black liquid into the air intake, and the engine is stumbling at idle. The liquid leaves an equally black rubbery residue, but both dissolve fairly easily with carburetor cleaner. Someone somewhere said this was because the PCV valve was blown and the engine is running lean.
I am fairly inexperienced with cars, so I could be wrong about what this is, but there's no other hose connecting to the air intake AFAIK.
Here is where the metal tube that the hose fits onto goes into the engine:
[image: where the other end of the hose goes into the engine]

Here is the (dismounted for diagnosis, but still in mostly the correct position) air intake, the other end of the hose, and the hole it clips into.
[image: the other end of the hose and the hole it goes into]

If this is the PCV tube and the valve is blown, how can I change it? This metal tube doesn't seem to come out. Some sources said the entire valve cover has to be replaced for this year model, but that sounds extortionately absurd if it is the case.
If this is not the PCV tube, is it supposed to be putting any liquid into the air intake?
Any suggestions for why the engine may be running rough? It has fresh fuel, new spark plugs and wires, and a clean air filter.

Edit: Here is a video of what I’m talking about. https://rumble.com/v3x8ocj-is-this-the-pcv-system.html

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same sheet of music here ... the engine in your Suburban is the 5.3L V8 ... is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're looking in the right place (at least by your images) for where the PCV is located on your Suburban. It should be located in the driver's side (left) valve cover towards the rear, pointing just about straight up. There should be a hose which is attached to it and plumbed into the intake manifold (IIRC). Whatever you're looking at (I really can't tell) does not look like the PCV at all.

Here's an image of the driver side valve cover (from RockAuto.com). If you were looking over the fender, this is what you'd see (with a bunch of coils and wires on top):

[image]

You shouldn't have to replace the entire valve cover, as the PCV is sold separately.
I have never personally taken one out, but I'd think if they sell them separate, you can replace it.

Comment: That makes sense, but then what is this, and why is there no other hose connecting to the air intake? I'll try to get a full video or something to show you what I'm talking about, and I'll look for the actual PCV. Thanks!

Comment: Video added to the question. I mumbled, so captions were added. You’ll have to turn them on, though.

Comment: If you don't mind, since this answer does not seem to be relevant, could you delete it? Nothing personal, but I feel like the label of (1 unaccepted answer) is driving away potential informers.

Comment: @TheLabCat - Actually no, because it does answer your question of "Is this the PCV".

Comment: As the video I added shows, there is no other tube connecting to the air intake; not from the location this answer describes, or any other. So, does that mean this engine does not have a PCV tube?

Comment: I have modified the question to hopefully better match what I really want to know, sorry for the confusion.